# mpd with bluetooth speaker has no sound

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, mpd

My environment has two audio output: HDMI and Bluetooth speaker. Usually both of them work correctly. For example,

```bsh
#this plays sound via bluetooth speaker
$ aplay -D default jingle.wav

#this plays sound via HDMI
$ aplay -D plughw:1,7 jingle.wav
```

However, `mpc play` doesn't play any sound. My `/etc/mpd.conf` is a default one except for the music directory. So

```bsh
music_directory     "smb://xxx.xxx.xx.x/some_directory"
...
audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "My ALSA Device"
    #   device      "hw:0,0"    # optional
    #   mixer_type      "hardware"      # optional
    #   mixer_device    "default"   # optional
    #   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
    #   mixer_index "0"     # optional
}
```

I use a remote music directory (`smb` protocol) and the connection is ok. According to `man mpd.conf`, the default value of `device` field is `"default"`. But `mpc play` plays no sound though I expect it plays via the bluetooth speaker as the `aplay -D default` command above. `sudo mpd --no-daemon --stderr` says

```
exception: OutputThread could not get realtime scheduling, continuing anyway: sched_setscheduler failed: Operation not permitted
avahi: Service 'Music Player' successfully established.
client: [0] opened from xxx.x.x.x:xxxxx
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
exception: Failed to read mixer for 'My ALSA Device': no such mixer control: PCM
```

The last line may be the cause, so I set the `mixer_type` field as `"none"`. But still no sound. `mpc play` successes and the current position (e.g. `00:56/3:20 (58%)`) progresses but no sound.

How can I use my bluetooth speaker? If I set `device` to `plughw:1,7`, `mpc play` actually plays sound via HDMI as the `aplay` command above. However, I would like to use the bluetooth speaker.

Environment:

```bsh
$ lsb_relase -d
Description:    Linux Mint 19 Tara

$ mpd --version
Music Player Daemon 0.20.18
```

I installed `mpd` via `sudo apt install mpd`.

Comment: Suggest you post your solution as an Answer tomorrow, so others may benefit from your hard work. Good job!

Comment: @K7AAY Thank you for your advice. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is perfectly been solved by [Music Player Daemon/Tips and tricks - PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Music_Player_Daemon/Tips_and_tricks#Local_(with_separate_mpd_user)). And [MPD with pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555103/mpd-with-pulseaudio) is also helpful.

The website is actually sufficient but let me write what I did. In the first place, I did set the `device` field of `/etc/mpd.conf` to `"alsa"` but this is wrong. A bluetooth speaker is by default managed not by `alsa` but by `pulseaudio` (at least on Linux Mint and though you can use a bluetooth speaker via `alsa` using e.g. `BlueALSA`). So the value of the field should be `"pulse"`. However, by default, `pulseaudio` is running in a user space while `mpd` runs system-wide. So `mpd` can't access the settings of the current user's `pulseaudio` session. To let `mpd` see the setting, you can turn on `pulseaudio`'s remote functionality:

```bsh
sudo cp /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/default.pa.bak
sudo vi /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

and change the line of

```bsh
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
```

to this (uncomment and add some words)

```bsh
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
```

and restart `pulseaudio` to reflect this change.

```bsh
#Note there is no `sudo` prefix.
#As written above, `pulseaudio` runs in a user session.
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Now you can access `pulseaudio`, using `tcp` protocol and via the ip address `127.0.0.1` (this is usually `localhost`). At last, `mpd`'s setting should be changed:

```bsh
sudo cp /etc/mpd.conf /etc/mpd.conf.bak
sudo vi /etc/mpd.conf
```

and set the value of `audio_output` field as below

```bsh
audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "arbitrary_name_which_you_like"
    server      "localhost"
}
```

and restart `mpd` to reflect the change.

```bsh
#Note there is `sudo` prefix.
sudo systemctl restart mpd
```

That's all.

---

Supplement:

By the way, the fact that `aplay -D default jingle.wav` succeeded but `mpc play` didn't comes from the difference of the running space, i.e. running system-wide or as a user session. So comparing the results is meaningless. I should have compared `mpc play` with `sudo -u mpd aplay -D default jingle.wav`. The latter command fails and this is an expected result.

Comment: This almost worked for me. I had to set the server value in audio_output to "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost"  but you got me real close, so thanks.